# JSF Primefaces Upload/Process/Download all on one page that enables Download after Upload

Tags: html, file, jsf, primefaces

I want a single page with an Uploader that processes the uploaded file, creates a new file, and makes that file available for Download.  I can get this all to work, except that I want the Download commandButton to be disabled until the processing has occurred and a file is available for download.  This is the part that isn't working.  The Download button is always enabled.

```
<h: form>
    <p: fileUpload id="upload" fileUploadListener="#{fileProcessor.process}" mode="advanced" />
</h: form>

<h: form>
    <p:commandButton id="download" value="Download" ajax="false" disable="#{!(fileProcessor.readyToDownload)}">
        <p:fileDownload value="#{fileProcessor.zipfile}" />
    </p:commandButton>
</h: form>
```

And here is the backing bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class FileProcessor {

    private InputStream zipfileInputStream = null;
    private boolean readyToDownload = false;

    public StreamedContent getZipfile(){
        return new DefaultStreamedContent(zipfileInputStream, "application/zip", "processed.zip");
    }

    public boolean isReadyToDownload(){
        return readyToDownload;
    }

    public void process(FileUploadEvent event){
        InputStream uploadStream = event.getFile().getInputStream();
        // a separate class processes the data, returns an InputStream
        zipfileInputStream = FileProcessProvider.getInstance().process(uploadStream);
        if(zipfileInputStream != null){
            readyToDownload = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not updating your components, use the `update` attribute to rerender the download button

Comment: I tried that, but I got a FacesException: cannot find component with expression "download" referenced from "j_idt28:upload"  and the page won't render at all

Comment: That's because you have it inside another form. Name your another for like `<h:form id="formOfTheButton">` and in your update use as `update=":formOfTheButton:download"`

Comment: Ok, let me add it as an answer for you.

Comment: See my answer with the second solution

Comment: YES!!!  That worked!  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update your command button in order to it to change its state. You do it either by moving the button the the same form and add an `update` attribute to it or you name your second form and use it. So:

First solution:

```
<h:form>
    <p:fileUpload id="upload" fileUploadListener="#{fileProcessor.process}" mode="advanced" update="download"/>

    <p:commandButton id="download" value="Download" ajax="false" disable="#{!(fileProcessor.readyToDownload)}">
        <p:fileDownload value="#{fileProcessor.zipfile}" />
    </p:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

Second solution:

```
<h:form>
    <p:fileUpload id="upload" fileUploadListener="#{fileProcessor.process}" mode="advanced" update=":secondForm:download"/>
</h:form>

<h:form id="secondForm">
    <p:commandButton id="download" value="Download" ajax="false" disable="#{!(fileProcessor.readyToDownload)}">
        <p:fileDownload value="#{fileProcessor.zipfile}" />
    </p:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks!